# IMAP Command with PHP VivOAuthIMAP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, imap

I am using the following lib : https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP

I would like to add a function call Search From that would enable me to search mails from a specific sender. Here's the additional function :

```
public function searchfrom($expeditor) {
    $this->writeCommannd("A" . $this->codeCounter, " UID SEARCH FROM \"".$expeditor."\" ");
    $response = $this->readResponse("A" . $this->codeCounter); 
    return $this->modifyResponse($response);

}
```

The result from the server is : "BAD" (nothing else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   /**
    * Search in FROM ie. Email Address
    * @param string $email
    * @return Array
    */
    public function searchFrom($email) {
        $this->writeCommannd("A" . $this->codeCounter, "SEARCH FROM \"$email\"");
        $response = $this->readResponse("A" . $this->codeCounter);      
        //Fetch by ids got in response
        $ids = explode(" ", trim($response[0][1]));     
        unset($ids[0]);
        unset($ids[1]);     
        $ids = array_values($ids);
        $stringIds = implode(",",$ids);     
        $mails = $this->getMessage($stringIds);         
        return $mails;
    }
```

I have added this to the Library. Check if it works for you.
https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP/blob/master/src/VivOAuthIMAP.php